# Add Symbol " to text

Tags: c#, symbols

*Hi ! 
I must add this symbol :* ***"***    *to text.*

*I have this code :*

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file))
{
    sw.WriteLine("HELLO : " + " < This symbol add to text );
}
```

How to add " Symbol ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the escape character `\` and than your desired character.

Example:

```
\"
```

Result:

```
sw.WriteLine("HELLO : \"SomeText\" bye!");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should escape your `"` with `backslash`:

```
sw.WriteLine("HELLO : \"");
```

Or use `verbatim strings` with `@` but you should add two double quotes:

```
sw.WriteLine(@"HELLO : """);
```

For more information see: [Escape Sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)